# How To Use Constants in Elixir Tests?

Tags: elixir

I'm defining a constant in my main module this way:

```
@end_digits_adjusters [11, 12, 14, 21, 22, 23]
```

Here's how I'm trying to test for it:

```
defmodule PriceOptimizerTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest PriceOptimizer

  test "get_random_adjuster() randomizer" do
    adj_num = PriceOptimizer.get_random_adjuster()
    is_in? = adj_num in @end_digits_adjusters
    assert is_in? == true

  end
end
```

That doesn't work.  But when I explicitly specify the constant value in the test it does work.  Like this...

```
is_in? = adj_num in [11, 12, 14, 21, 22, 23]
```

Am I missing a step somewhere to get Elixir to recognize the module constants in the tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shared constants, which are popular in other languages, is not a popular pattern in Elixir. I have personally found that most of the time I don't need to use the pattern. But there are some applications I've built relay heavily on them.

When I do need them, I have a constants module I use the following module:

```
defmodule Constants do
  @moduledoc """
  An alternative to use @constant_name value approach to defined reusable
  constants in elixir.

  This module offers an approach to define these in a
  module that can be shared with other modules. They are implemented with
  macros so they can be used in guards and matches

  ## Examples:

  Create a module to define your shared constants

      defmodule MyConstants do
        use Constants

        define something,   10
        define another,     20
      end

  Use the constants

      defmodule MyModule do
        require MyConstants
        alias MyConstants, as: Const

        def myfunc(item) when item == Const.something, do: Const.something + 5
        def myfunc(item) when item == Const.another, do: Const.another
      end

  """

 defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      import Constants
    end
  end

  @doc "Define a constant"
  defmacro constant(name, value) do
    quote do
      defmacro unquote(name), do: unquote(value)
    end
  end

  @doc "Define a constant. An alias for constant"
  defmacro define(name, value) do
    quote do
      constant unquote(name), unquote(value)
    end
  end

  @doc """
    Import an hrl file.

    Create constants for each -define(NAME, value).
  """
  defmacro import_hrl(file_name) do
    list = parse_file file_name
    quote bind_quoted: [list: list] do
      for {name, value} <- list do
        defmacro unquote(name)(), do: unquote(value)
      end
    end
  end

  defp parse_file(file_name) do
    for line <- File.stream!(file_name, [], :line) do
      parse_line line
    end
    |> Enum.filter(&(not is_nil(&1)))
  end

  defp parse_line(line) do
    case Regex.run ~r/-define\((.+),(.+)\)\./, line do
      nil -> nil
      [_, name, value] ->
        {String.strip(name) |> String.downcase |> String.to_atom, String.strip(value) |> parse_value}
      _ -> nil
    end
  end

  defp parse_value(string) do
    case Integer.parse string do
      :error -> filter_string(string)
      {num, _} -> num
    end
  end

  defp filter_string(string), do: String.replace(string, "\"", "")
end
```

Couple notes:

- They work in pattern matching!
- Don't import your constants module. Its hard to find where they are defined
- Alias the module for brevity `alias MyConstantsMod, as: Const
- This module also supports working with Erlang hrl files
- pay attention to the `require` statements. The `define` is a macro.
- Converting a list of C `#define` statements is only a few key strokes when using sublime's multi cursor and vi key bindings :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, [Elixir's module attributes](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html) are available only within the module where are defined. This is due fact that those attributes are online in code during compilation phase.

If you want to make them *publicly* accessible, you need to wrap it with function, eg:

```
defmodule MyMod do
  @test "hello"

  def test, do: @test
end
```

So:

```
MyMod.test # => "hello"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there an elegant workaround to constructing tests that use constants, without having to wrap the constants in a module?

Comment: @Emily No, no other way.